# Get filter choise in template

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-filters

Google suggests to use different titles and different meta tags on each site page. In my Django project I use - https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter 
And now I have for example - ordering desc and ordering asc google recognise as different pages. As we should set title and meta tag description different on each page which google crawl recognises, how could I get info about ordering and other filter settings from django-filter in html template? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how could I get info about ordering and other filter settings from django-filter in html template?

There isn't builtin functionality for inspecting the applied filters and their corresponding information. However, `FilterSet`s use Django forms internally to validate the incoming data. You should be able to use the `filterset.form.cleaned_data` to see what filters have been applied and what their cleaned values are.